# Best practice for putting space between functions that are multiplied

Tags: spacing

I am wondering what is the best practice for putting space between functions that are multiplied.

Here is a specific problem I have.  I want to render `\cos{x} u(x)`, which is meant to represent the product of two functions `\cos{x}` and `u(x)`.  However, direct rendering of this expression produces a result without enough space between `x` and `u(x)` and looks like `\cos{x u(x)}`:

[image]

In order to avoid this problem, I actually have been surrounding the function name `u` with `\mathop` to write `\cos{x} \mathop{u}(x)`.  This puts a proper space in front of `u(x)`:

[image]

However, I just learned that surrounding a single letter with `\mathop` shifts the baseline, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/mathop-shifts-the-baseline-declaremathoperator-doesnt?noredirect=1&lq=1).  (You can see that `u` is shifted upward in the above rendering.)  Using `\operatorname` instead of `\mathop` avoids this issue, but it uses an upright rather than italicized font for a single-letter function name.

Obviously, the easiest solution would be to put a space explicitly by `\cos{x}\,u(x)`, but I don't want to disturb TeX's automatic spacing scheme as argued convincingly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28936/extra-space-between-number-and-variable-in-math-mode).  Is there a better way to inform TeX that there should be a space between two functions multiplied?

Comment: `\mathop{{}u}`  would do what `\operatorname` does but without the font change

Comment: IMHO I would use parenthesis around x in this case.... Or write `u(x)\cos x`. But I understand it's a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: Why, why, mathematicians like to write a function as f(x), but write the trigonometric functions as cos x? I would use a `\cdot`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, I think omitting parentheses when obvious increases readability by avoiding nested parentheses.  For example (cos x - sin x) / (cos x + sin x) is easier to understand than (cos(x) - sin(x)) / (cos(x) + sin(x)) to me.

Comment: @dashmile then why did you write u(x). I agree is more clear if you only use trigonometry, but once you start using your own functions, you lose this clarity.

Comment: If we do not add parentheses or some kind of class changing like `\mathop`, how should LaTeX know if you mean `cos(xu(x))` or `cos(x)u(x)`? I think @Rmano gives you a good suggestion.

Comment: @mickep, that's why I used  `\cos{x}` rather than `\cos x`.  Then it should be clear that only `x` is the argument of `\cos`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, you are asking why I don't use `u x` for `u(x)` like `cos x`.  When the function name is single-letter like `u`, it is not clear whether it is a function or variable, so we need parentheses, I guess.  When the function name is multiple-letter like `cos`, it is clearer that it is a function rather than a variable, especially if it is written with upright font rather than variable's italicized font.

Comment: @dashmile yes, see my post and choose!

Comment: @dashmile You are mentioned **TeX** automatic spacing scheme, no LaTeX spacing scheme. LaTeX macro does nothing with spaces in math formulae.

Comment: @wipet, thanks for pointing that out.  I updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Thin space or not, readers will be puzzled about the meaning of cos x u(x). If you write u(x) cos x nobody would misunderstand. If you insist in cos x u(x), just use `\,` which is the command of choice for such cases where you *do* want to override the automatic spacing.

Comment: As @egreg points out, inserting `\,` here is the preferable method, and I believe that you can find an example in the TeXbook recommending that.  In fact, there's a list of examples on p.169 regarding explicit input spaces.

Answer (score 5):

TeX primitive command `\mathop` does vertically centering of is argument, if this argument consists only from single object. That is the reason why `\mathop{u}` centers the `u` at math axis. If the argument of `\mathop` has more than single object then the argument is at baseline.

You can define

```
\def\op#1{\mathop{{}#1}}
```

and use

```
\cos x \op u(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

With this code

```
\[\cos x \,u(x)\]
```

you dont have problems. The rendering is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I mentioned in OP that the explicit use of `\,` is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but it works without calling guru's hair sectioning.

Answer (score 2):

For absolute clarity, consistency and beauty use eq(1)

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
\cos{(x)}\cdot \operatorname{u}(x)\\
\cos x \operatorname{fn}x
\end{align}
\end{gather}
```

[image]